# Can't install npm > npm install lite-server -g

Tags: node.js, npm

when I hit enter this comes up.

changed 170 packages, and audited 171 packages in 12s

6 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: So what's the problem? Seems all installed fine ...

Answer (score -1):

I can't seen an error. it's just a warning message.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer